# Is $1s2s$ state an upper bound of Helium excited states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, atoms, orbitals

Generally people says that the state $1s(1)2s(1)$ $ ^1S$ is an excited state of Helium  atom . Variation theorem guaranties that the expectation value of this state is greater than the ground state, that  is  $E[(1s(1)2s(1)]\geq e_0$ where $e_0$ is the ground state energy.
For example since $1s(2)$ $ ^1S$ is the ground state  we can show that the state $1s(1)2s(1)$ $ ^3S$ is an upper bound of the first  excited state of Helium.

Now let $e_1$ be the first excited state of the Helium atom, is there any theorem that guaranties  that we have $E[(1s(1)2s(1) ^1S ]\geq e_1$ ?

Comment: Which state do you mean, the singlet of the triplet?

Comment: I mean a  Singlet

Comment: The triplet 1s2s state is the lowest excited state. See https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/energy1.pl?encodedlist=XXT2&de=0&spectrum=He+I&submit=Retrieve+Data&units=1&format=0&output=0&page_size=15&multiplet_ordered=0&conf_out=on&term_out=on&level_out=on&unc_out=1&j_out=on&lande_out=on&perc_out=on&biblio=on&temp=

Comment: I know that triplet state is the lowest excited state.  I am not asking if singlet sate is the lowest  am asking if it is un upper bound of the excite states of helium

Comment: "assuming that $1s(2)$ $ ^1S$ is the ground state " This is not an assumption but a hard fact.

Comment: You are right  I will edit the question

Comment: `The question is unclear. $1s(1)2s(1)$ $ ^3S$ **is** the first excited state so it is the upper, lower bound etc.

Comment: We can not solve Schrodinger equation exactly . The state $1s(1)2s(1)$ $^1S$ is an upper bound by variation methods

Comment: Your "We" excludes quantum chemists. Physics has a **blind spot** for what quantum chemistry achieves on multi-electron systems. Highly accurate quantum chemical atomic calculations could easily fit on your smart phone. Quantum chemical methods accurately solve the Schrödinger or the Dirac equation with many Slater determinant wave functions. Radiative corrections can be added and finite nuclear size can also be accounted for.

Comment: yes but it is never exact. So we need theorems to  show that our calculation is right. Assuming that the singlet state in question is not an upper bound state of the first excited state. Applying variation methods and with a large number of bases we will arrive more close to the ground state an not to the first excited state

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by 1s 2s state. A single determinant perhaps? How are the orbitals determined ? Or the real thing ? Please clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

There is no such theorem. What you have is experimental data and very accurate quantum chemical simulation (any atom with more than 1 electron for some reason is chemistry). There are many more excited states and the singlet certainly is not the highest of these. You could learn a lot by looking at the complete He I level set at https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/energy1.pl?encodedlist=XXT2&de=0&spectrum=He+I&submit=Retrieve+Data&units=1&format=0&output=0&page_size=15&multiplet_ordered=0&conf_out=on&term_out=on&level_out=on&unc_out=1&j_out=on&lande_out=on&perc_out=on&biblio=on&temp=

Comment: We can proof for example that the triplet is  a upper bound of excited states assuming that singlet is a ground state

Comment: @amiltonmoreira I get the impression that you limit yourself to the 1s2s configuration.

Comment: I am not understanding what you mean

Comment: @amiltonmoreira There are many excited states higher that the 1s2s triplet or singlet. Did you take a look at the NIST database?

Comment: It seems that is a confusion between me and you . I am not interested in experimental data. I  am talking theoretical

Comment: @amiltonmoreira Theory and experiment essentially give the same answers here. Besides, all physicists are interested in experimental data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to Wikipedia it is known as the [Aufbau principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle) (or Madelung rule, as I've been taught in school).

Comment: that is not a theorem

Comment: Indeed it is not. By definition theorem is a general proposition not self-evident but proved by a chain of reasoning; a truth established by means of accepted truths. This principle, however is empirically measured, not theoretically postulated.